# ngTable - Server side pagination getData error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I am trying to implement a server side table using ng-table. But when I am using `getData`, it either says that `$defer.resolve is not a function` or `params is not defined`.

I can get the `params` if `$defer` is not used in the `getData` function.

This is a part of my code:

```
angular.module('ngTableTest', ['ui.router', 'ngTable'])
.controller('Table', function($state, NgTableParams){
   var vm = this;

   vm.niceTable = new NgTableParams({}, {
      getData: function($defer, params) {
        $http.get('/app/getdata')
            .success(function(data) {
               params.total(data.count);
               $defer.resolve(data.data);
            });
        }
      });
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you hould include $q to use $defer
try this

```
angular.module('ngTableTest', ['ui.router', 'ngTable'])
.controller('Table', function($state, $q, NgTableParams){
   var vm = this;

   vm.niceTable = new NgTableParams({}, {
      getData: function(params) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/app/getdata')
            .success(function(data) {
               params.total(data.count);
               deferred.resolve(data.data);
            });
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: Well, that fixed the `params` error but it does not display the returned data in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue, here is my solution:

```
angular.module('ngTableTest', ['ui.router', 'ngTable'])
.controller('Table', function($state, $q, NgTableParams){
   var vm = this;

   vm.niceTable = new NgTableParams({}, {

     getData: function(params) {

         var promise =  
           $http.get('/app/getdata')
            .success(function(data) {
               params.total(data.count);

               // here you can do some data manipulation 
               return $q.resolve(data); // this can be skipped if no data manipulation is required
            });
           }
        });
        return $q.resolve(promise); 
});
```

Please note in current version of NgTable, getdata has only one parameter, only params, earlier it was two, $defer and params.

Seems getdata needs to return a resolved promise. In the question, promise was resolved within success method but not directly in getdata method.

Anyway this is a working solution, but 've reached the solution only by trial and error. I wish some expert shed some light on how $q.resolve work and getdata functions return value.